# How to output box coordinates produced from Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: xml, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API to detect objects. These objects are trained using as following
1) Draw boxes around objects in images
2) use labellmg to convert these boxes into xml file(this xml file contains dimention of boxes), and use xml to train API.

In the output, I get image drawn with box-highlight. How do I output XML coordinates of this box in a xml file?

Comment: You can save cood in a numpy list & then output them.

Comment: @Beta I posted a detailed version of my question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343678/store-tensorflow-object-detection-api-image-output-with-boxes-in-csv-format) would you mind going through it, thank you in advance