# How to define own model using Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I have 2000+ training images(of custom farm structures) and I want to define my own model using Tensorflow. I researched (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md). This is a very high-level documentation. Can anyone help me on how to go about doing this?

Comment: this is awfully broad.. can you formulate a more specific question?

Comment: unfortunately no (the reason is I searched days and coudnt not understand how to start with defining my own model using this API), I have trained and tested this API on my custom trained images but it was using Googles pretrained model, I posted a solution to how I did that here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343678/store-tensorflow-object-detection-api-image-output-with-boxes-in-csv-format). I am stuck due to lack of documentation by Google on defining my own model.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation serves as a high level guide in itself, but you essentially need to create a `DetectionModel`-based class.

You will need to design and implement the methods defined abstractly in the `DetectionModel` class [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/model.py) such that you create a model that is an instance of this abstract core class. How you design those functions is up to you, but the documentation you linked above provides some good guidelines.

Comment: could you point me towards a link where Google trained their custom model using model.py script in that way I can compare it with this one you mentioned and I can get to know what changes I should make to define a custom model